# How to display Media image with alt attribute in paragraph twig template

Tags: theming, entities, media, 9, paragraphs

I'm trying to access alt attribute as in given example [Get Media Image URL in Paragraphs Twig Template - Drupal 8](https://createdbycocoon.com/knowledge/get-media-image-url-paragraphs-twig-template-drupal-8)

But there is an example how to access alt and title...

> That's easy, too. You should use the following syntax, switching out the bold for the machine name of your image field: {{ content.field_custom_image['#items'].alt }}

this is not worked for me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have worked out this i have access to alt in my case its:

```
 {% if paragraph.field_media_image is not empty %}
    <img src="{{
      file_url(
        paragraph.field_media_image.entity.field_media_image.entity.fileuri
      )
      }}"
      alt="{{
      content.field_media_image[0]['#media'].field_media_image[0].alt
      }}" />
  {% endif %}
```

So solution is:

```
{{ content.field_media_image[0]['#media'].field_media_image[0].alt }}
```

Comment: You should just render the media item properly and all of this will 'just work'. `{{ content.field_media_image }}` - the rest is controlled from Manage Display on this particular media type. There is no need to manually write out img tags.

Comment: Thank you @Kevin In my case i need to do in that way.  Also it renders lots undesirable divs as fields templates in action when you use {{ content.field_media_image }} in my project i need to avoid this ...

Comment: You just add a twig file for the field and media type that has no extraneous markup then.

Comment: @Kevin it will change all media files ... which i no need ... but this is usable for other tasks ... you are right :)

Comment: If you want to translate in twig, just add `|t` and use `{{ content.field_media_image[0]['#media'].field_media_image[0].alt|t }}`

Answer (score 2):

Digging in Twig certainly works, though it does have limitations (such as translation support).

If you need custom output, you could try:

```
function getMediaFieldImage($mediaField = NULL, $imageStyle = NULL) {

  if ($mediaField && $mediaField->entity) {

    $langcode = \Drupal::languageManager()->getCurrentLanguage()->getId();

    // Get image.
    $mediaImage = $mediaField->entity
      ->get('field_media_image');

    // Check for translation.
    if ($mediaField->entity->hasTranslation($langcode)) {

      // Get translated image field.
      $mediaImage = $mediaField->entity->getTranslation($langcode)->get('field_media_image');
    }

    // Get image attributes.
    $alt = $mediaImage->alt;
    $width = $mediaImage->width;
    $height = $mediaImage->height;
    $title = $mediaImage->title;

    // Get image entity.
    $mediaImageEntity = $mediaImage->entity;

    // Get image mime type.
    $mediaImageMimeType = $mediaImageEntity->getMimeType();

    // Get image file URI.
    $mediaImageEntityUri = $mediaImageEntity->getFileUri();

    // Set image URL.
    $url = \Drupal::service('file_url_generator')->generateString($mediaImageEntityUri);

    // Set image style URL if not .svg.
    if ($imageStyle && $mediaImageMimeType !== "image/svg+xml") {
      $url = \Drupal::service('entity_type.manager')
        ->getStorage('image_style')
        ->load($imageStyle)
        ->buildUrl($mediaImageEntityUri);
    }

    return [
      'url' => $url,
      'alt' => $alt,
      'width' => $width,
      'height' => $height,
      'mimeType' => $mediaImageMimeType,
      'title' => $title,
    ];
  }

  return NULL;
}
```

Set it like:

```
function MYTHEME_preprocess_paragraph(&$variables) {
  $variables['mediaImage'] = getMediaFieldImage($paragraph->get('field_name'), 'medium');
}
```

And in Twig:

```
<img src="{{ mediaImage.url }}" width="{{ mediaImage.width }}" height="{{ mediaImage.height }}" alt="{{ mediaImage.alt }}" />
```